# OpenStreetMap Nominatium. Поиск адресов построек в окружности или прямоугольнике

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding

Задача: найти все адреса построек в окружности (lat; lon; radius) или на худой конец в прямоугольнике. Конкретнее, нужно составить список из десяти ближайших к точке построек, которые не дальше, чем в ста метрах от неё.

Делаю небольшое приложение, которое должно копить информацию о различного рода постройках: магазинах, музеях, спортивных школах и подобное. Обязательно должны указываться и адрес, и точка на карте(lat; lng). Найти места по адресу используя Nominatium Search уже умею. И могу найти один объект в точке, используя Nominatium Reverse.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в как решить поставленную задачу или что я пропустил в данной [документации](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/)!

Comment: в свое время делал подобную задачу... решение было следующим... брал точку куда был клик, это точка была точкой середины прямоугольника. Так как адреса домов, зданий и т.д. это просто координата в виде точке Lon | Lat, то делал проверку какие точки попадают в этот прямоугольник. Важно! Если будут делать проверку пол любой геометрической фигуре, учитывайте масштаб, что бы проверяемый прямоугольник рассчитывался с учетом текущего масштаба. Есть исходники этого решения, но на Delphi.

Comment: Ну, да, с углами прямоугольника несложно разобраться. Простая тригонометрия. Но мне бы хотелось узнать как выглядит запрос на сервис. Вот запрос для получения точки по адресу выглядит так:
let res = await this.$axios.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search', {
          params: {
            q: this.address,
            format: 'json'
          }
        })

И нашел как узнать адрес в точке, а не несколько в окружности рядом.
Можно мне пример запроса, пожалуйста?

Comment: задачу которую решал, позволяла загрузить все адреса и их точки в память, а потом по ним искать. По ресурсам - это не накладно даже для существенно большего региона. Чуть позже буду за ПК, сброшу код получения адресов по координатам. Координаты прямоугольника  вычислить не проблема, если есть центральная точка и знаем масштаб.

Comment: А есть ли способ не грузить в память, а работать с онлайн-сервисом? Или у тебя всё именно так? Просто, пока искал, нашел немало примеров, где ребята сперва в течении длительного времени делали копию данных определённой страны/региона, а уже потом работали с тем, что загрузили. Такое мне не очень подойдёт...

Comment: да это без проблем. но не всегда удобно, как правило подобные задачи, нужны для конкретных регионов и лучше периодически обновлять локальную БД, чем постоянно с сервера тягать ответы.... я посмотрю код, как получал координаты по адресам и сброшу его.

Comment: Буду благодарен!)

Comment: нашел запросы которые делал, выложил как ответ, надеюсь решение подойдет....)

Answer (score 0):

Отвечая на комментарии ниже к вопросу (это не Nominatium Reverse, но надеюсь как решение подойдет).

Имея такой скрипт в bat файле:

```
@ECHO ON
osmconvert.exe XXX.osm.pbf -b=11.3,11.8,12.8,12.05 -o=XXX.xml --all-to-nodes --statistics
osmfilter.exe XXX.xml --keep="place=city OR building OR addr* OR name OR amenity" --drop-author --drop-version -o=xxx-buildg.xml
osmconvert.exe xxx-buildg.xml -o=result.csv --csv-headline --csv-separator=; --csv="@id addr:city addr:street addr:housenumber name amenity @lat @lon"
```

можно по указанным координатам получить *.csv файл, со следующими полями:

```
@id;addr:city;addr:street;addr:housenumber;name;amenity;@lat;@lon
121644503;;;;FOOOSTREET;;12.9830241;17.5048717
.....
```

потом его разобрать и по координатам точек и названием улиц, проверить попадают они в наш прямоугольник или нет. Все это можно завернуть в GET запросы на сервер и обрабатывать прям в коде...

Comment: Спасибо, но это немного не то. Меня интересует та часть, где происходит взаимодействие с сервисами OSM. Вот пример такого взаимодействия:
let res = await this.$axios.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search', {
  params: {
    q: this.address, //Тут строка, например "Северодонецк Строителей 21"
    format: 'json'
  }
})
Это запрос на поиск точки по указанному адресу. Я посылаю строку, а мне обратно JSON с массивом наиболее подходящих вариантов.
Но мне нужно ещё узнать как найти адреса построек и всяких достопримечательностей в окружности. И вот этого я никак не нахожу.

Comment: ок я Вас понял, в том решение что сверху, обратите внимание, что можно через osmconvert.exe XXX.osm.pbf -b=11.3,11.8,12.8,12.05 задать квадрат, с которого получим все адреса, может в этом направление тогда посмотреть...., единственное Вам локально нужно иметь область в формате osm.pbf где будет проходить поиск...

Comment: Ну, мне локально нельзя грузить. Не подходит это.
Сейчас работаю над тем, чтобы получить все объекты node/way/relation в указанном прямоугольнике, отфильтровать постройки и потому уже через nominatium /research найти адрес ближайших из них. Главное потом не забыть это тут опубликовать)
Но, в любом случае, спасибо за то, что хотел помочь!

Answer (score 0):

Я не смог найти как запросить адреса по площади с помощью Nominatium, однако решил попытаться разобраться в данных с самого OpenStreetMap. Запросив XML с некоторого густонаселённого прямоугольника обнаружил, что внутри много замкнутых линий, которые имеют теги обозначающие постройки и их тип - Дома, Гаражи, Церкви, Сервисы, и многое другое. Дальше я просто считал среднее арифметическое точек ломанных и запрашивал с Nominatium адреса уже по ним.

Минусы:

- Способ весьма нагруженный, делает один запрос на OpenStreetMap и кучу запросов (по каждой точке) на Nominatium
- Вы могли верно дать точку, но нет гарантии, что вам вернётся ожидаемый адрес.
- Точно так же нет гарантии, что по нескольким разным точкам Вы не получите одинаковые адреса.

Вообщем я выкручивался как мог! Код, правда, не выжил, но идея, надеюсь ясна. А если нет - пишите! Всегда рад помочь